# Bind template reference variables to ngModel while using reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm using a reactive form.when an input state is invalid i show an error.this is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input name="username"
           type="text"
           class="form-control"
           id="username"
           formControlName="username"
           #username/>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"
         *ngIf="formDir.form.controls.username.touched && 
                formDir.form.controls.username.invalid">
        This field is required.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password"
           id="password"
           class="form-control"
           name="password" />
</div>

<pre>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

every time i want to use ngIf to show a validation error i have to write this unwieldy code:

```
*ngIf="formDir.form.controls.username.touched && 
       formDir.form.controls.username.invalid">
```

it's more persecutor when you have more objects to validate.

by following documents on angular.io and [this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jxkgqklvokp?file=src%2Fapp%2Freactive%2Fhero-form-reactive.component.ts) i found a solution but i have to create an instance of every form control that i want to access it on view.

i'm looking for a solution like something we can use in template driven validation, using a temporary variable and ngModel like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" #username="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="username.touched && username.invalid" class="alert alert- 
danger">Email is required</div>
```

As i understand from [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9363) there is no way to achieve this but this link is old and it may exists a solution in newer version of angular.

can you help me?

thanks

Comment: What about writing your own structural directive, that will take 
 1. control as an input parameter
 2. error that should be check (by default required)?

Answer (score 2):

Use an ngIf expression followed by a let, to rename the result of the expression:

```
<div *ngIf="formDir.form.get('username'); let c" class="form-group">
    <label for="username-id">Username</label>
    <input
       type="text"
       class="form-control"
       id="username-id"
       [formControl]="c" />
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="c.touched && c.invalid">
        This field is required.
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also say:

```
<div *ngIf="formDir.form.controls.username; let c" ...>
```

If you don't happen to have a div or some other element you can use for the ngIf (the value of which is assumed to be always truthy), you can use an ng-container.

Answer (score 0):

To show error based on validation for each field you can try :

```
<div *ngIf="formDir.form.controls[fieldName].invalid" class="alert alert- 
danger">Email is required</div>
```

for this you do not need any other variable, in form-controls object we have validation. Please let me know if you need any more details

Comment: I think Abolfazl Davoodi Shandiz was asking for a bit more elegant solution. I've run into similar problem and don't like using this long chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an error component:

```
  <div>         
    <input type="text" formControlName="foo">
    <control-error [control]="foo" [errorName]="'required'">
      Type your error message here
    </control-error>
  </div>
```

The error component template:

```
<div *ngIf="control.touched && control.errors?.[errorName]">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Gain access to the form control instance that you pass to the error component with either a getter in the component class [as shown in angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms): `get username() { return this.form.get('foo'); }` or use  `form.get('foo')` right within the template.

Comment: you can pass also the "error" like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741343/angular-forms-how-to-avoid-multiple-ngif-divs-for-validation-error-messages/57744709#57744709)

Comment: Thanks to Eliseo for helping me improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to use NgModel with a FormGroupDirective will result in the following error.

`ERROR Error: ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.`

The FormControlName directive doesn't export itself for template bindings. However, the [FormControlDirective does as ngForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective#template-variable-references). The catch is that [FormGroup.controls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#controls) are of type AbstractControl which [results in a type error conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284894/type-abstractcontrol-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type-formgroup) with strict template type checking. This can be correct with a method that takes the control name and type casts to FormControl.

[Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h96dw8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```html
// component.component.html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <hello name="{{ name.value }}"></hello>
  <input #name="ngForm" [formControl]="control('name')" />
</form>
```

```js
// component.component.ts
form = new FormGroup({ name: new FormControl(`Name`) });

control(name: string): FormControl { return this.form.controls[name] as FormControl;
```

This can just as easily be done with template driven forms without duplicating any logic in the component class.

```html
// component.component.html
<hello name="{{ name.value }}"></hello>
<input #name="ngModel" [ngModel]="Name" />
```