# How not to display an error message if the field was not touched?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

How to display the "Email is required" message if a field has been touched

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control w-100 mt-2" type="text" formControlName="login" required>
    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls.login.errors?.required">
        Email is required
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Really I hate write always the codition, So, some time ago, I made a "component error" in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741343/angular-forms-how-to-avoid-multiple-ngif-divs-for-validation-error-messages/57744709#57744709), but all the others answer are ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `touched`.

```
<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls.login.touched && form.controls.login.errors?.required">
    Email is required
</span>
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lmupvf?file=src/app/contact-form/contact-form.component.html)

### References

[Validating input in template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-template-driven-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form.controls.login.touched`

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control w-100 mt-2" type="text" formControlName="login" required>
        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls.login.touched && form.controls.login.errors?.required">
            Email is required
        </span>
    </div>
```