# Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more

Tags: typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

we recently upgraded from ng 7.2.15 and typescript 3.2.4 to angular v8.2.14 and typescript v3.5.3.
Passing the form group from a parent component to child component is no longer working.

Below is my child component:
child component. ts

```js
@Component({selector:'edit-overview'})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {  
   public OverviewFormGroup : FormGroup
   constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.OverviewFormGroup = <FormGroup>this.controlContainer.control;
  }
}
```

child.component.html

```html
<div [formGroup] ='OverviewFormGroup'>
</div>
```

and my parent component

Parent.component.html

```html
<div [formGroup]="Form1">
  <edit-overview [formGroup]="Form1.controls.OverviewFormGroup">
  </edit-overview>
</div>
```

Parent.component.ts

```js
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.Form1 = this.fb.group({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    OverviewFormGroup: new FormGroup({
            description: new FormControl('', [Validators.nullValidator])
          })
    })
  }
}
```

It throws this error: Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more at the parent template line.

Earlier passing a formgroup from parent to child was no longer an issue. Am i missing something here?
I have already given value for controls in the Form group declaration.

Comment: my mistake.Should have changed parent template to formGroupName instead of [formGroup]. Worked after that!

Answer (score 33):

Good question, it is an obscure error. The error comes from typesafety features! Because Angular cannot know that it is a form group from the way you're accessing it (it just knows it is an `AbstractFormControl`), you need to **tell it**!

### Option 1: Use `as` to make the type explicit

So for example if you have:

```
  mainForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['Max'],
    address: this.formBuilder.group({
      street: ['PayneStreet'],
      zip: [50000]
    })
  });
```

In order to let Angular know that you're actually accessing a form control, you need to tell it:

```
  get addressForm() {
    return this.mainForm.get('address') as FormGroup;
  }
```

The important part is the **`as FormGroup`**. Like this Angular knows that it's actually a `FormGroup` and not just an abstract form control. Then you can go ahead and use it in the html:

```
<app-address-form [addressForm]="addressForm"></app-address-form>
```

Find the stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-forms-input

### Option 2 (preferred): Define the nested group separately

It is actually easier and more typesafe to just build the second form separately and then to attach it to the main form:

```
  addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    street: ["PayneStreet"],
    zip: [50000]
  });

  mainForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ["Max"],
    address: this.addressForm
  });
```

and in the html (same as above)

```
  <app-address-form [addressForm]="addressForm"></app-address-form>
```

Like this, Angular knows already that `addressForm` is of type `FormGroup` and not just of type `AbstractFormControl`

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-forms-input-2

Comment: Good answer, solved my error, had to "interrogate" the AbstractFormControl using the as keyword, thanks!!

Comment: Hi @bersling, I was wondering how you would use your trick within a for loop. `ng-container *ngFor="let addressForm of addresses.controls"` taking `address` is a `FormArray` filled with `FormGroup`.

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet, check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67366344/8607675). I tested it with strict templates and it`s working.

Comment: @Alexander Thx, but in your example, what if you would like to do the following `demoForm.variable` ?

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet, sorry for losing your time, after another test, I`ve got many errors related to reactive forms.

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet I guess you already have found out but just create a getDemoForm() method in your ts file that returns your form as a FormGroup and use getDemoForm().variable in your html template file.

Comment: This answer is correct, I add something complementary for my specific case, I had to create a function that receives an **AbstractControl** type parameter   `function(parameter: AbstractControl): FormGroup {
      return form as FormGroup;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Using the formbuilder api, you dont need to explicitly define form controls. Try:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.Form1 = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      OverviewFormGroup: this.fb.group({
        description: ['', [Validators.nullValidator]]
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lazy workaround

[bersling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62446852/11135174) is the solution to follow.

That said and if you have not the time to refactor, you could just add `$any()` and it will resolve your issue

```html
<div [formGroup]="Form1">
  <edit-overview [formGroup]="$any(Form1.controls.OverviewFormGroup)">
  </edit-overview>
</div>
```

Answer (score -10):

Dependending on how comfortable you are with your *strictness*, you could turn it off for Angular templates by setting `strictTemplates` to `false` in your `tsconfig.json` like this:

```json
{
 ...,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "strictTemplates": false,
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this please.